# Compass in not compiling sass to css

Tags: css, sass, gulp, compass

after running gulp sass files are not compiled into CSS. I have checked directories and all looks fine.There is no error, gulp is running as if there is no .SASS file in the src/styles directory. Nothing is produced in dist/css folder. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks
Here is the gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    compass = require('gulp-compass');

gulp.task('compass', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/styles/main.sass')
        .pipe(compass({
            sass: 'src/styles',
            image: 'src/images',
            css: 'dist/css',
            generated_images_path: 'dist/images',
            sourcemap: true,
            style: 'compressed'
        }))
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});


gulp.task('default', function () {
    gulp.watch('./src/styles/**/*.sass', ['compass']);
    gulp.watch('./src/images/**/*', ['compass']);
});

my directory structure

root
 | 
 |
 +-- src
 |    |  
 |    +-- styles/sass
 |    +-- images
 | 
 +-- dist
      |  
      +-- css
      +-- images
```

Comment: Hi, I'd change your second line to "var sass = require('gulp-sass');" not var sass = require('gulp-compass'). You need to import compass to your sass then compile all the sass. I don't think compiling just the compass will get you any output. See here for more: http://ryanchristiani.com/getting-started-with-gulp-and-sass/

Comment: Its not working. It throws an error.

Comment: Please post the error. Have a look at that article I posted and make sure your code is similar.

Comment: Here is the link to the screenshot of the error. https://imgur.com/KqiVzZO

Comment: Here is another error after making sure all the code and directory structure is in place : https://imgur.com/a/fXpl8

Comment: Have you checked that you have gulp sass installed? https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass Looks like you don't have it, reading the error.

Comment: I installed sass and tried it again. No error this time but my css folder is still empty. I tried changing the extensions from .scss to .sass in gulpfile.js as well but it doesnt work

Comment: Make sure the directories you call in your gulp file exist and are reachable, and what error are you getting in console when you run gulp/sass?

Comment: I figured it out. Compass was not added to the environment variables. So i installed it as ruby gems instead of using npm and since ruby was in the environment variables it all worked. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Great! Remember you can also @import compass, or any other scss stylesheets, to the main sheet and they will render with the styles without using a gem; but the way you did it is just fine.

Comment: Post what you did at the end of your question to help others.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative, i will try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was solved by installing compass and sass as ruby gems and adding ruby path to the environment variables.